# Mergesort OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying to implement a MergeSort recursive algorithm to sort an array but I keep getting this problem  on the merge part and I don't understand why I'm getting this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
It marks the error at line 21

Here is the code for just the merge part, the recursive part seems to have no problems

```
public static void Intercala(ArrayList<Alumno> L, int ini, int mitad, int fin){
    int i=ini;
    int j= mitad+1;
    int k = ini;
    ArrayList<Alumno> B = new ArrayList <Alumno>();

    while(i<=mitad && j<=fin){
        if (L.get(i).get_matri() <= L.get(j).get_matri()){
            B.add(k,L.get(i));
            i++;
        }
        else{
            B.add(k,L.get(j));
            j++;
        }
        k++;

    }
    if (i>mitad){
        for(int h=j; h<=fin; k++){
            B.add(k,L.get(h));
        }
            k++;
    }
    else{
        for (int h=i; h<=mitad;k++){
            B.add(k,L.get(h));
        }
        k++;
    }
    for(i=ini; i<=fin; i++){
        L.set(i, B.get(i));
    }
}
```

Can someone help me out? I already tried to recheck the code but nothing seems to be helping

EDIT: Already tried extending the memory and still throws this error

Comment: Basically, you ran out of memory to create new objects in. Line 21 created the object that broke the camel's back.

Comment: B.add(k,L.get(h)); is a slow operation on an ArrayList if k isn't near the end.

Comment: Recursive algorithms are memory-intensive. What about modify max heap size by adding -Xmx parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, I don't see anything wrong with the logic. The only conclusion that I can come up with is how ArrayList allocates memory.
Default size is 10 and when you reach limit you double the memory allocated. It continues to do this.

The problem could also be how much memory an Object Alumno takes up. With this sort of explosion of allocation of memory from the ArrayList it is possible to run out of space. If you want to use List, I suggest using a LinkedList, where the size doesn't automatically double when you reach capacity.

There may be a problem with your recursion function, but I am assuming it is correct.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After the while loop.

```
if (i>mitad){
    for(int h=j; h<=fin; k++){
        B.add(k,L.get(h));
    }
        k++;
}
else{
    for (int h=i; h<=mitad;k++){
        B.add(k,L.get(h));
    }
    k++;
}
```

These 2 for loops will run infinitely.

Because h won't change in the loop.